# How to write this python condition in single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe that contain some data. I want to apply a condition on this dataframe.

When i wrote the code like this:-

```
import pandas as pd 
data_store = pd.read_excel("101010.xlsx") 
fff = data_store[data_store.Price > 20] 
print(fff.sort_values("Total Sale", ascending=False))
```

The program is running and return(show) dataframe elements value as i want like this:-

```
Total Sale      Price
100000           64
95000            21
94000            25
70000            30
61000            41
59000            23
54000            50
40000            55
```

But when i wrote that code in single line like this:-

```
import pandas as pd
data_store = pd.read_excel("101010.xlsx")
fff = (data_store[data_store.Price > 20]) and (data_store.sort_values("Total Sale", ascending=False))
print(fff)
```

I get error like this:-

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Moli/PycharmProjects/first/main.py", line 3, in <module>
  fff = (data_store[data_store.Price > 20]) and (data_store.sort_values("Total Sale", 
  ascending=False))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1327, in __nonzero__
  f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
  ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() 
  or a.all().
   
  Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please can some body help me.
How i can write this condition in single line like this:-

```
(data_store[data_store.Price > 20]) and (data_store.sort_values("Total Sale", ascending=False))
```

Thank you in advance :) :) :)

Comment: `data_store[data_store.Price > 20].sort_values("Total Sale", ascending=False)` may do the work for you @Amelia

Comment: @ShivamJha Does `sort_values` return the sorted df or does it perform it in place? Because if it performs it in place you would not have a reference to the sorted and filtered dataframe.

Comment: @Adirio Pandas `sort_values()` function sorts a data frame in Ascending or Descending order of passed Column. It’s different than the `sorted()` Python function since it cannot sort a data frame and particular column cannot be selected.

Syntax:
`DataFrame.sort_values(by, axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind=’quicksort’, na_position=’last’)`

Comment: @ShivamJha I know what `sort_values` does, I asked if it did it in place or if it returned the sorted dataframe. The answer is that it returns the sorted dataframe by default and has an argument to do it in place, so your proposed solution does work.

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a logical and, it compares the previous and next statements, evaluate them to booleans and perform a logical and.

Your previous and next statemens are:

```py
data_store[data_store.Price > 20]
data_store.sort_values("Total Sale", ascending=False)
```

Both return a dataframe (filtered by price) so basically you are trying to do a logical and operation to two dataframes. As the error reports, a dataframe doesn't have a boolean value, it is ambiguous.

So summing up, `and` does not concatenate the actions, it performs a logical and, which breaks before dataframes can't be converted to boolean values.

What you want to do, as @ShivamJha pointed out in a comment, is the following:

```py
import pandas as pd 


data_store = pd.read_excel("101010.xlsx") 
fff = data_store[data_store.Price > 20].sort_values("Total Sale", ascending=False)
print(fff)
```